# I want to display different components based on different endpoint data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am working on a project where I need to display a different template/component based on what my endpoint response is.

For example

```
{data: {type: 1, textToDisplay: 'I want beans'} }
```

Should inject Component 1 into the main app template.

If the data is

```
{data: {type: 2, textToDisplay: 'I want cheese', numberToDisplay: '101' } }
```

Should inject Component 2 into the main app template and of course Component 2 would be different to Component 1 because there's extra properties.

I really don't want to use bad practice by appending elements into the main app template nor do I want to write a massive template with `[if]` directives as we could have many, 5-8, different components to render and it would bloat the template.

What's a suitable way?

Comment: Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score 2):

As @Günter mentioned, you can use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="addCmp()" #theBody>add</button>
  `,
  directives: [BaseDynamicComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;
  cmp:ComponentRef;

  constructor(injector: Injector,private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

  addCmp(data){
    console.log('adding');
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(BaseDynamicComponent).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmp = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
      //and you can set your BaseDynamicComponent's 'extra' properties here
      this.cmp.instance.numberToDisplay = data.numberToDisplay;
    });
  }
  }
```

This will add the BaseDynamicComponent under the #theBody element.

Here's an example plunkr:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tizrf1Nu9pu7gQc8cVTR?p=preview)

If you click the add button it will add a new component with its test field assigned to "the test"

```
this.cmp.instance.test = "the test";
```

Or you can predefine the components like in @Günter's answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/5706293) and then append them accordingly

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated, use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead. See my link above.

Comment: I see you updated the code already. No need to inject `DynamicComponentLoader` if you don't use it ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm updating it right away sir, It was an old template :D

Comment: Thanks you lot I'll take a look next week and get back to you, but thanks